# Spring Cloud Config Server - How to download binary file

Tags: spring, git, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I have a Spring Cloud Config Server with the usual properties files in the git repo:

```
|--application.yml
|--app1.yml
```

I also added a binary file

```
|--mybinaryfile
```

Normally to access the properties I would ask for

```
http://myconfigserver/app1/dev
```

Is it possible to download the binaryfile through the config server? I have tried  with

```
http://myconfigserver/mybinaryfile
```

and

```
http://myconfigserver/mybinaryfile/dev
```

but they didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it:

`http://myconfigserver/*/dev/master/mybinaryfile`